# WiX: Custom Actions don't run when using msiexec /i Setup.msi /qn (quiet mode installation without UI)

Tags: wix, custom-action, windows-installer, silent-installer

Our problem is that custom actions don't run when using msiexec /i Setup.msi /qn (quiet mode installation without UI). They only run with normal installation with UI.

In our Product.wxs for example, we have defined the following:

```
<Binary Id="SetupCustomAction" SourceFile="$(var.SetupCustomActions.TargetDir)$(var.SetupCustomActions.TargetName).CA.dll" />

<CustomAction Id="UPDATE_CONFIG" BinaryKey="SetupCustomAction" DllEntry="UpdateConfiguration" Execute="commit" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    ...
    <Custom Action="UPDATE_CONFIG" After="InstallFiles"><![CDATA[NOT Installed AND USEIMPERSONATE="0"]]></Custom>
    ...
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Do we have to use ["Quiet Execution Custom Action"](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html), trying this out didn't help though!

Please help!

Comment: How is the **USEIMPERSONATE** condition being set?

Comment: @Ritmo2k:

1. `<Property Id="USEIMPERSONATE" Secure="yes" Value="1" />` 

2. `<CustomAction Id="DISABLE_IMPERSONATE" Property="USEIMPERSONATE" Value="0" Execute="firstSequence" />`

3. `<InstallExecuteSequence>
     ...
        <Custom Action="DISABLE_IMPERSONATE" After="AppSearch"><![CDATA[PREVIOUSINSTALLSCOPE="1"]]></Custom>
     ...
    </InstallExecuteSequence>`

Comment: What does a verbose log say about the sequence of events, add `/l*v file.log` to your command in the question and make note of the properties being set, changed and what Windows Installer evaluates the condition to.

Comment: Logs will be very useful as Ritmo2k said. Usually this type of thing ends up being the condition isn't what you think it is.

Comment: In the log file it says: `"MSI (s) (5C:D0) [14:06:28:363]: Skipping action: DISABLE_IMPERSONATE (condition is false)"` The DISABLE_IMPERSONATE custom action is defined like this: `<CustomAction Id="DISABLE_IMPERSONATE" Property="USEIMPERSONATE" Value="0" Execute="firstSequence" />` and in InstallExecuteSequence: `<Custom Action="DISABLE_IMPERSONATE" After="AppSearch"><![CDATA[PREVIOUSINSTALLSCOPE="1"]]></Custom>`

Comment: I.e. that custom action which should set USEIMPERSONATE to "0" fails to execute because its PREVIOUSINSTALLSCOPE condition is false. PREVIOUSINSTALLSCOPE is looked up in the registry: 

`<Property Id="PREVIOUSINSTALLSCOPE">
     <RegistrySearch Id="_5937F138_D59E_4E4F_A19E_AF51B7259E87" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Name="InstallScope" Type="raw" />
</Property>`

Answer (score 0):

The obvious explanation is that USEIMPERSONATE has the value 1 so the custom action will not run, but I assume perhaps you are setting it to 0 on the command line.

Apart from that it would be useful to know if the install actually succeeds, because if it normally requires elevation with a UAC prompt then this UAC dialog will not be shown, so the custom action will not run elevated and it will fail. The install might succeed because Commit custom actions run after the install, so "check" is not relevant because the install cannot roll back. If you configure that CA as an install custom action it might fail and roll back the install. So after InstallFiles is also not relevant because it's a Commit CA.

The log should show something.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found the cause of the error and a fix for it: The `ALLUSERS` OR `PREVIOUSINSTALLSCOPE` (read from the registry) Properties must be set to "1". That way, the `DISABLE_IMPERSONATE` Custom Action gets run and sets the `USEIMPERSONATE` Property to "0". Then `UPDATE_CONFIG` and other Custom Actions get run.

To sum up, the solution is:

1. Change `DISABLE_IMPERSONATE` Property to this: `<Custom Action="DISABLE_IMPERSONATE" After="AppSearch"><![CDATA[ALLUSERS=1 OR PREVIOUSINSTALLSCOPE="1"]]></Custom>`
2. Call msiexec like this: `msiexec /i Bechtle.A365.Office.Client.msi /qn ALLUSERS=1`

Thanks to @Ritmo2k, @Brian Sutherland and @PhilDW for pointing me to the right direction.